# Flutter Image loading and caching

Tags: image, caching, flutter, cache-control

Here is my use case:

1. I am getting the list of URLs of images.
2. I want to display and cache them in the database, not only for a particular session so for the next time it should not do a web service call.

Our app is working offline as well. I tried a few libraries like `flutter_advanced_networkimage` and `flutter_cache_manager` but I'm getting quite lag and most of the times app crash.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Save it in your app's temp directory using the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package:

```
import 'dart:io';

// https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

final Directory temp = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final File imageFile = File('${temp.path}/images/someImageFile.png');

if (await imageFile.exists()) {
  // Use the cached images if it exists
} else {
  // Image doesn't exist in cache
  await imageFile.create(recursive: true);
  // Download the image and write to above file
  ...
}
```

It will persist through app launches and only gets deleted when the user personally clears the cache or reinstalls the app.

Answer (score 6):

I've been using [`cached_network_image`](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image), works as advertised